# iOS, trying to get insertRowsAtIndexPaths to work

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UITableView that loads 10 records initially when the data comes back from a PHP call, when the scrollbar reaches to the last item i make a PHP call to get the next record and display this data in the cell. I am trying to use insertRowsAtIndexPaths but i keep getting this error when i hit numberOfRowsInSection the app crashes:

```
  uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

### CODE

```
 -(void)renderScrollThreadInfo:(NSDictionary*)dic{

                NSDictionary *thread = [dic objectForKey:@"thread"];
                countNewThreadsBottom = 0;
                if((NSNull*)thread != [NSNull null]){

                int t_ID;
                    int t_U_ID;
                    int t_C_ID;
                    NSString *t_Name;
                    NSString *t_Description;
                    NSDate *t_Created;
                    int t_Flagged;
                    int t_Rated;
                    NSString *firstName;
                    NSString *lastName;
                    NSString *categoryName;

                NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                    for(NSDictionary *dict in thread)
                    {
                    if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_ID"] != [NSNull null]){
                    t_ID = [[dict objectForKey:@"T_ID"] intValue];
                    }
                    if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_U_ID"] != [NSNull null]){
                    t_U_ID = [[dict objectForKey:@"T_U_ID"] intValue];
                    }
                    if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_C_ID"] != [NSNull null]){
                    t_C_ID = [[dict objectForKey:@"T_C_ID"] intValue];
                    }
                    if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_Name"] != [NSNull null]){
                    t_Name = [dict objectForKey:@"T_Name"];
                    }
                    if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_Description"] != [NSNull null]){
                    t_Description = [dict objectForKey:@"T_Description"];
                    }
                    if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_Created"] != [NSNull null]){
                    NSString *timestampString = [dict objectForKey:@"T_Created"];
                    double timestampDate = [timestampString doubleValue];
                    t_Created = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestampDate];
                    }
                    if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_Flagged"] != [NSNull null]){
                    t_Flagged = [[dict objectForKey:@"T_Flagged"] intValue];
                    }
                    if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"T_Rated"] != [NSNull null]){
                    t_Rated = [[dict objectForKey:@"T_Rated"] intValue];
                    }
                    if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"U_FirstName"] != [NSNull null]){
                    firstName = [dict objectForKey:@"U_FirstName"];
                    }
                    if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"U_LastName"] != [NSNull null]){
                    lastName = [dict objectForKey:@"U_LastName"];
                    }
                    if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"C_Name"] != [NSNull null]){
                    categoryName = [dict objectForKey:@"C_Name"];
                    }

                    ThreadInfo *threadObj = [ThreadInfo new];
                    threadObj.iD = t_ID;
                    threadObj.userId  = t_U_ID;
                    threadObj.catId = t_C_ID;
                    threadObj.name = t_Name;
                    threadObj.description = t_Description;
                    threadObj.timeStampCreated = t_Created;
                    threadObj.flagged = t_Flagged;
                    threadObj.rated = t_Rated;
                    threadObj.firstName = firstName;
                    threadObj.lastName = lastName;
                    threadObj.category = categoryName;

                    c = true;
                    [tmpArray addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:countNewThreadsBottom inSection:1]];
                    countNewThreadsBottom += 1;

                    [tableViewThreads beginUpdates];
                    [tableViewThreads insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                    [tableViewThreads endUpdates];

                    [threadsArray addObject:threadObj];
                }


                //[tableViewThreads reloadData];
                }

            }

            - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
            {
                return 2;
            }

            -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
                if(section == 0){
                if(tableViewThreads == tableView){

                    NSLog(@"xfhdh %d", [threadsArray count]);
                    return 10;

                }

                }else{
                if(tableViewThreads == tableView){

                    return 1;

                }

                }

                if(tableViewPosts == tableView){
                return [postsArray count];
                }
                return 0;
            }

            -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


                if(tableViewThreads == tableView){
                NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
                ThreadTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

                int sec = indexPath.section;

                ThreadInfo *threadInfo;

                if(indexPath.section == 1){
                    threadInfo = (ThreadInfo*)[self.threadsArray objectAtIndex:[threadsArray count] - 1];

                    if (cell == nil)
                    {
                    cell = [[ThreadTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

                    [cell setupView:threadInfo];

                    }



                    cell.labelFirstName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", threadInfo.firstName,threadInfo.lastName];

                    cell.labelTimestamp.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:threadInfo.timeStampCreated dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
                    cell.labelTimestamp.text = [cell.labelTimestamp.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"AM" withString:@""];
                    cell.labelTimestamp.text = [cell.labelTimestamp.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"PM" withString:@""];

                    cell.labelThreadName.text = threadInfo.name;
                }else{
                    threadInfo = (ThreadInfo*)[self.threadsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                    if (cell == nil)
                    {
                    cell = [[ThreadTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

                    [cell setupView:threadInfo];

                    }



                    cell.labelFirstName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", threadInfo.firstName,threadInfo.lastName];

                    cell.labelTimestamp.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:threadInfo.timeStampCreated dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
                    cell.labelTimestamp.text = [cell.labelTimestamp.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"AM" withString:@""];
                    cell.labelTimestamp.text = [cell.labelTimestamp.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"PM" withString:@""];

                    cell.labelThreadName.text = threadInfo.name;


                }

                if(sec == 1){
                    int r = indexPath.row;
                    int g = 0;
                }


                //cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                return cell;

                }
                if(tableViewPosts == tableView){
                NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell2";
                PostTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

                PostInfo *postInfo = (PostInfo*)[self.postsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                if (cell == nil)
                {
                    cell = [[PostTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

                    [cell setupView:postInfo];
                }



                cell.labelUserName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ posted...", postInfo.firstName,postInfo.lastName];
                cell.labelCreated.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:postInfo.timeStampCreated dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
                cell.labelCreated.text = [cell.labelCreated.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"AM" withString:@""];
                cell.labelCreated.text = [cell.labelCreated.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"PM" withString:@""];
                cell.labelMessage.text = postInfo.message;
                return cell;
                //[cell.contentView addSubview:[self setupThreadItem:threadInfo]];
                }

                return nil;
            }

            - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
                NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell2";
                if(tableViewThreads == tableView){

                return 122;

                }
                if(tableViewPosts == tableView){
                PostTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
                CGFloat h;
                PostInfo *postInfo = (PostInfo*)[self.postsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                if (cell == nil){

                    cell = [[PostTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
                    [cell setupView:postInfo];
                }
                cell.labelUserName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ posted...", postInfo.firstName,postInfo.lastName];
                cell.labelCreated.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:postInfo.timeStampCreated dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
                cell.labelCreated.text = [cell.labelCreated.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"AM" withString:@""];
                cell.labelCreated.text = [cell.labelCreated.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"PM" withString:@""];
                cell.labelMessage.text = postInfo.message;

                [cell setNeedsLayout];
                [cell layoutIfNeeded];

                h = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height + 1;

                return h;

                }
                return 0;
            }


            -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
                return 60;
            }


            - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
            {
                if(tableViewThreads == tableView){
                //NSLog(@"%d %d",[indexPath row], [threadsArray count] - 1);
                if ([indexPath row] == [threadsArray count] - 2) {

                    ThreadInfo *threadInfo = (ThreadInfo*)[threadsArray objectAtIndex:[threadsArray count] - 1];
                    int tid = threadInfo.iD;


                    dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

                    // 3) Load picker in background
                    dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{


                    NSString *searchItem = textFieldSearchThreads.text;
                    NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Category=%d&TID=%d&SearchItem=%@",rowCategory, tid, searchItem];
                    NSString *response = [self setupPhpCall:myRequestString :@"getThread.php"];


                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                        if(response.length > 0){
                        [self renderScrollThreadInfo:[response JSONValue]];
                        }

                    });

                    });
                }
                }

                if(tableViewPosts == tableView){
                //NSLog(@"%d %d",[indexPath row], [threadsArray count] - 1);
                if ([indexPath row] == [postsArray count] - 1) {

                    PostInfo *postInfo = (PostInfo*)[postsArray objectAtIndex:[postsArray count] - 1];
                    int pid = postInfo.iD;


                    dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

                    // 3) Load picker in background
                    dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{


                    NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TID=%d&PID=%d", chatThreadId, pid];
                    NSString *response = [self setupPhpCall:myRequestString :@"getStandalonePost.php"];


                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                        if(response.length > 0){
                        //[tableViewPosts scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
                        [self renderScrollPostInfo:[response JSONValue]];
                        }

                    });

                    });
                }
                }
            }
```

Comment: did you try to reload tableView ?

Comment: Your `numberOfRowsInSection` looks pretty messed up. It is returning constant values instead of the number of items in your array - the error message tells you what is wrong - you called `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` but the value returned by `numberOfRowsInSection` was still 1

Comment: no because i thought the whole point of using insertRowsAtIndexPaths is not to use reload data

Comment: Step through your `numberOfRowsInSection` method with the debugger.  Your log statement references the array, but then you return a hard-coded value of 10.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are returning incorrect number of rows in -numberOfRowsInSection function. Check if you are returning number of rows including the inserted rows as per condition.